# CSS/HTML problem with footer page in my project

Tags: html, css, footer

I have a problem with the footer only in some page.
In the HomePage i've this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/itndn.png

In many of the other page i've this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzzQd.jpg

i don't know why only in main page the footer works. This is the code:
**main.hbs**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Blocco Note</title>
    <!-- LINK -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    {{> navigation }}
    <main class="container p-5">
      {{> messages }}
      {{> errors }}
      {{{ body }}}
    </main>
    {{> footer }}

    <!-- SCRIPT -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script language="javascript"> function emailCurrentPage() { window.location.href = "mailto:?subject=" + document.title + "&body=" + encodeURI(document.location); }</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.css**

```css
body {
  background: #4DB6FA;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #25A7FD, #4DB6FA);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #25A7FD, #4DB6FA);
}

.logo {
  width: 50%;
}

.footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2780E3;
  color: white;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.jumbotron {
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px grey;
}

#about .display-4 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#about .col-4 {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px grey;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.card {
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px grey;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card-text {
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px grey;
  text-align: center;
}
.card-header {
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px grey;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.alert {
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

**footer.hbs**

```html
<div class="footer text-center py-3">© 2020 Copyright: Blocco Note</div>
```

Why i've this problem? I tried to set position: relative, bottom:0px, left:0px, clear:both, but didn't work.

Comment: by default the html and body will be the height of the content. if you have very little content then it may not fully fill the available viewable space. You can set your html to have a min-height of 100vh and give the body a height of 100% to fill it out

Comment: If you want the footer to appear at the bottom of the screen when there is not enough content above it to fill the screen, you can use the [sticky footer](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/) technique.

Comment: you could also set the footer `position: absolute`, for sticking at the bottom, always (with some more edits, like spacing above it etc).

Comment: @BillyBrown are you sure he wants a sticky footer and not one that just displays on the bottom of the page?

Comment: @zgood i tried to set in css, html {min-height: 100vh;} and body{height:100%;} but didn't work.

Comment: @DanieleVallorani sorry ya that will just make the page the correct height but you still may need to `absolute` position your footer to the bottom and include some bottom padding on your body for it to sit in (like a gutter), so that it doesn't cover up any content. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vLb5d4g1/)

Comment: @zgood, yeeah i tried with footer absolute and body relative... and now WORKS. this is the solution: html{height:100%;}
body{padding-bottom:50px; min-height:100%; position:relative;}
.footer{position:absolute; bottom:0; height:50px;}

Comment: ya thats how... just make sure the padding-bottom of the body and the footer height match so that the footer doesn't cover up any content

Comment: yes i checked that footer doesn't cover up any content. Is perfect. Very thanks

Comment: @zgood I made the assumption that the poster wanted a sticky footer rather than a floating footer only because I know that people dislike footers that take up screen-space at all times (especially on mobile).